# Adding admob to a canvas in a extends View class

Tags: android, view, admob, android-canvas, extends

I am trying to implement admob in my app, but I can't get it working.

I have a Class A, which is the main class, it extends activity.
I have a Class B, which is the class that is called when the application start. I have the following piece of code in class A to archive this:

```
B b = new B(this);
setContentView(B);
```

In class B I have a canvas with test and bitmaps. I want to put an ad on the canvas with admob, but I can't archive this. Class B:

```java
private AdView adView;
int[] degree = { 90, 180, 270, 360 };// random graden eindposities pijl
// int width, height;
Random rand = new Random();
Typeface font;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();// degree,x,yaxis
Region region;// region die klikbaar is om het pijl te bewegen
AlertDialog alertDialog;
LinearLayout layout;
    
public YesNo(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
    
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   //do something
}
 
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Do something
    invalidate();
}
```

i have tried to implement admob with this code(among other):

```java
public void ads() {
    adView = new AdView((Activity) getContext(), AdSize.BANNER,
             "xxxxxxxxxxx");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Create a linear layout
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout((Activity) getContext());
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
    layout.addView(adView, params);
}
```

I searched hours for a solution but I can't find any.

Can somebody help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `AdView` need to be a part of your content view.  The `LinearLayout` you created in your `ads()` function.  Second, you need to create an AdRequest and load the ad with that request:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR); // get test ads on emulator.
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals#addadview) for more information on how to set up your AdView.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ads` function, you do not actually use the LinearLayout you create - you need to put that into another layout or directly into your activity, using `setContentView`

Comment: How do i put it in another lay-out. And by doing that, isn't it gonna draw on top of the canvas causing the canvas to never appear on the screenen?